# How do i remove references to an old unity version in the hub so i can reinstall that version

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason Unity does not allow for two instances of the same version to be installed on my laptop.  This is especially annoying because it shows that I have a version of Unity that I do not have (that I previously have uninstalled) in Unity Hub.  What I want to do is remove this listing of the version so I can install it correctly, because since it thinks it is already installed, it will not let me install this version

[image]

here is what unity hub looks like

[image]

I already tried manually installing it from the website, but when I open the unity.exe that is installed from the installer, it just opens unity hub which fixes nothing.

Another solution that I tried that I found online (back when this version was installed manually) is opening one of the projects that I had created with that version via the file explorer.  While this did open Unity, it did not link it to Unity Hub and since it did not do this, I was not able to login to Unity (and therefore not able to use the asset store, or try out the micro-games in the
"learn" tab)

If anyone who works for unity reads this: please revert unity back to how it was before unity hub.  I used unity 2017 for a couple years without any issues and recently decided to update.  Unity hub is worse in every single way and doesn't even fulfill its one function which is to install unity :(

thank you for coming to my ted talk

Edit: I deleted C:\Users[my username]\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub. This allowed me to manually set the unity location from inside the hub. It still doesn't work though. This happens: i.imgur.com/Fwd079U.png

Comment: Simply uninstall it. If you already did simply tell the HuB to remove the link. There should be an option `Remove from Hub` if the `Unintsall` is not available. Btw Unity installs are completely sandboxed .. you can simply hard delete the installation folder of a version in case of doubt ;) and then restart the Hub and install the version again

Comment: this did not work for me but thank you for embedding the images, hugo bc I don't have the reputation too

Comment: @derHugo None of those suggestions work. A) The problem is the hub thinking a version is installed that isn't, you can't "hard delete" a folder that doesn't exist anymore. B) You can't `Remove from Hub` an install that no longer exists, at least in my own experience, it breaks the hub both times I've dealt with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This glitch has been fixed in the most recent version of Unity Hub(2.4.1).  Thank god.  
Here is an excerpt from [the unity hub release notes](https://unity3d.com/hub/whats-new):
Bug Fixes:
(...)

- Download progress bug fix: located editor version was marked as corrupt when first download attempt from hub is interrupted

Comment: Still isn't fixed

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I've found so far, as mentioned in one of the comments, is to delete the hub's app data from `%appdata%\Roaming\UnityHub`

On Windows:

1. Close Unity Hub and all it's processes from the Task Manager
2. Move the entire UnityHub folder to a backup location
3. Re-launch Unity Hub.

You shouldn't need to re-add any projects to the project list, those seem to be cached elsewhere. It also seems to recognize any versions of Unity that really are still installed.